# How to get Sum of different columns in a table based on condition on each of them

Tags: ms-access

I have a table which has 30 different fields. I want sum of all the columns only when they have particular values. I don't want value of a field to be considered for summing when the value in it doesn't satisfy particular condition. For example, I have 5 fields id, Score1, Score2, Score3, Score4. I want sum of all these different fields only when they don't have values -8 or -9 in them. How can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

In "real" SQL you would use a CASE statement, but it looks like that isn't supported in Access (except via VBA).  Try using something like:

```
iif(score1 <> -8 and score1 <> -9, score1, 0) + iif(score2 <> -8 and score2 <> -9, score2, 0) + ....
```

Check out this for details on iif http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response. Let me explain in more detail. I have a form and table in which the values c_id,ch_id, Score1, Score 2, Score3, Score4 are entered and saved. The form that I want to calculate Scores is total different form. The requirement is that I have a combo box which has all the values c_id in them. Now based on that I have to generate a report which has c_id,ch_id,Total Score.                    I am really sorry if question is lengthy. The thing I don't get is how can I use the condition that you specified in a query in VBA.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that outside of VBA, there is no CASE statement, but you can use iif in a query or VBA statement.  In VBA, you'd use `myVariable = iif()` and in a query it is `myAlias: iif()`.  I'm not good with Access though, you may have to say `myAlias: (iif() + iif() + ...)`

Comment: Hey EvilBob...Thanks a lot...I made some changes and IIF can be used both in query and VBA.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can use a query like this,

SELECT  c_id,ch_id,  (IIF(Response4 <> -8 AND Response4 <> -8, Response4 , 0)) + 
(IIF(Response3 <> -8 AND Response3 <> -8, Response3 , 0))  AS Score
from Teacher_Questionnaire ;

In VBA you can use the same as follows:

Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim sSQL As String
    Dim sSQL1 As String

```
sSQL = " SELECT  SUM ( " & _
```

"(IIF(Teacher_Questionnaire.Response4 <> -8 AND Teacher_Questionnaire.Response4 <> -8, Teacher_Questionnaire.Response4 , 0)) + " & _
"(IIF(Teacher_Questionnaire.Response3 <> -8 AND Teacher_Questionnaire.Response3 <> -8, Teacher_Questionnaire.Response3 , 0)) ) AS Score" & _
"from Teacher_Questionnaire where ch_id = 99"

```
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL)

If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    Me.TxtLevel1 = rs!Score
Else
    Me.TxtLevel1 = "N/A"
End If

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: Yep, that's the idea I was getting at!